# express, socket.io server for browser client and node.js client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to set-up an express server with socket.io that will allow node.js clients and browser clients to connect. The browser connects with no problem. The node.js client using socket.io-client give an error: 
`unhandled socket.io url`

Server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    io = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var host = 'localhost';
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Gulp is starting my app on PORT: ' + port)
});
io = io.listen(server);

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

    socket.on('clientMessage', function(jsonData, from) {
        socket.emit('serverMessage', 'Got a message!');
        console.log('Data being sent from', from, 'is:\n' + jsonData);
    });
});
```

Client:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')

var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.222:8080', {reconnect: true});

socket.emit('clientMessage', 'Hello', 'Pi-Voyager');
```

Comment: I test your code, it run welll.

Comment: What was the behavior? It tells me Unhandled socket.io url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the way I was requiring my dependencies. It worked on other versions but on my current version it did not.

```
node -v
v0.12.4

"express": "^4.13.1",
"socket.io": "^1.3.6",
"socket.io-client": "^1.3.6"
```

With these versions, the following code works:

Server

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Gulp is starting my app on PORT: ' + port)
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

    socket.on('clientMessage', function(jsonData, from) {
        socket.emit('serverMessage', 'Got a message!');
        console.log('Data being sent from', from, 'is:\n' + jsonData);
    });

});
```

Client

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')

var socket = io.connect('http://10.1.0.47:8080', {reconnect: true});

socket.emit('clientMessage', 'Hello', 'Pi-Voyager');
```